# the generator of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\ltimes \mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: group-theory

We know that $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\ltimes \mathbb{Z}^2 \in SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$, and $SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$ is a finitely generated group. What about  $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})\ltimes \mathbb{Z}^2$? Is it finitely generated? If so, what is its generator and relation?

Comment: $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$ are both $2$-generated. So the answer is yes.

Comment: So what's the relation? @spin

Comment: Use the presentation $\langle a, b : a^4 = 1, a^2 = b^3 \rangle$ for $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$.